# Is it best practice to use PHP Throwable while dealing with MySql DB Transactions?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I need some clarification on the use of Throwable in PHP while dealing with mysql transactions. Somewhere I read it is not a good practice to use Throwable everywhere we get errors since Throwable will Catch ALL errors.

So lets consider below code snippet

```
public function test()
{
    $db->beginTransaction();

    try {
        //Some code here
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $db->rollBack();
        throw $e;
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Assuming that db is handling a lot of data and many methods are using this same method for db queries. Now situation is like if I get error(Suppose TypeError or any other) while doing any db transaction so catch won't be able to handle it since it is an error and transaction will not be able to rollback in that case.

In such situations, would it be best practice to use Throwable all things considered or not ?

Comment: You can extend the Exception class so that you can deal appropriately with each Exception you define. see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php. So, if `beginTransaction()` throws a `TransactionException` (which you have created), your framework could catch it, roll back the transaction, then show an error page. Whether this is best practice or not, I don’t know; but it addresses your concern.

Comment: Hi Tim, I was not concerned about Exception since I am already catching Exceptions from the code. I was asking more about handling Errors like TypeError or any other error while doing DB transactions. Hope the question is clear.

Comment: My point was that you are catching generic exceptions, but you can throw specific ones and take specific action based on the type of exception thrown. If you need to catch errors as exceptions, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php.

Comment: Thank you Tim for your input but I don't think ErrorException will catch errors like TypeError and I don't want to give too many catch blocks for each type of errors separately. That's why asked for clarity on Throwable since it can be used for both Exceptions and Errors.